# Lua dynamic variable

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to use my energy (a rapidly changing variable) to describe the color of my bar.

```
function(progress, r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2)
    local maxMana = UnitPowerMax("player");
    local currMana = UnitPower("player");
    if (currMana > maxMana) then
        currMana = maxMana;
    end
    if currMana < 120 then
        return (currMana*2), (currMana/2), (255/currMana), a1
    else
        return r2, g2, b2, a2     -- blue
    end
end
```

This gives me the same result as `r1, b1, g1, a1`

Comment: It is indeed part of a wow addon called weakauras. I'm  certain it's on a 0-255 scale as entering colors manually does work

Comment: Are you sure your mana is below 120? This number would be actual only at extremely low level.

Comment: Yes, I used code found in another script, UnitPowerMax("player") works regardless of class and in this case I'm on a rogue where max energy is 135. I can see the color change, just not to the colors I want (it seems to default to r1, b1, g1, a1)

Comment: Well, r/g/b/a1 is not actually used in this function and it looks and works just as expected. This is likely to be problem in another part of code.

Comment: Where are you assigning the return values of this function call?

Comment: what is your question? and what is the purpose of progress, r1, g1, b1 and a1. You don't use them in the function.
Please provide code where you use the function.

Answer (score 0):

Check those Weak Aura import codes:

```
!TJvBVjUrq4)lr6Kivqo)(lv6(qifYLtein25stvKHf8AW354LU2obNpWV9o7U2GbSVY176jv1QqwwpE2X7m78mpJXt2Z1ZbbdPEojEokNjRFMUNZtEo(SpWnNIM9zFkz5fKicfemuM)rHpQYh18gkbRcmXuc1ht7wSepNUrHV(kI6VEIlHeLgcIsMHIWSL5KsM9mMMesIHlLvLukxV30Yz98NJ9CC(JmefVEs)SOO1tUFrykiKINdR0nFjmFoLKTSCnoHVIz7phuw6ccD0YuqVeHlk0OQRiXDfjURiXDfzMIOzLRYjjfrtflpmoSywamnzbFoCvknC(CWve20DJa(u(oeLrrGPYMIFghN6KfeeUYZz8fN74o2X98Bbf53XZ59yuu6IT6EdfZ115MEdgaIxIJIUYV0Fad5SG8YOy4o8Vph24pdpWy0t4cLYy7ANLrOCyh54Jzlse3EFVb30)UbcL2UNtlJapJDfcVM4JlImRgfeKGtzrliEKIPXOOpwEmQOblmEge2VHeY8Ml6n0T3TmHHpHyH0Qr0Iytmjgg9HietHXcHj4zKyWnbB8ekm(41EZjZXPp7ufs1VGazgjSBefuS17oY1D01d61hmvafcNWPkkfXtDf(yFMurK05IB71Byzc2vX8ieOygZ40HHx37HBZcpfYbGhCq4CXjtELyjBdfwjvnIG44VWyr2nm9PmacT58HLcXpI3vEkaVItpqmK3m7aHZIqjhAb)qW0Zaj5hClkAg(aHzj4Xclb4wkjc3WEs9a5lFEzdB3abaSblPuVNmgf7pUwhnHvtypHBkhuEiOXn0gmmjlnkKL7m6o3bxnShSPia0LxDrwP2Yx1uXXpmHH8CXRGlEZm4bKLKsEsC96pS(dbzXCxT1PWvte)frGIKRNSQD(7Uy81OLNDjo9go(fU4gscppP1MB1fNKct7tO3bq9wNiG6NCA7nZ(zqRF7HAEeZ459RN8U1tciuaI26K3CMsq71tyFDs7v)KSKu7C2yLftXPz04wIfdYXX(BtM73Xs1qYstws1qtvwvZWlOJM9UvSt5(F9vfAaRwfpxPQWXP92QchL(PnugRk4D7b5Dl9rmkPSIVH0acZVMDFOpRu(5W1nrPuHizl9YrrPagjnlra)qrVGYtsPzyVU)f0mL(VNJ8goNl2w7544DyptoTs39Px2H3PW8iU))nq80rwIhX)ITGilcH1Wi9j4Kkmi3Zrum)fiR9EkcAy4(nZ2WbGJr(OKdlhF0mahWGuqcO9(pE5d9dKV)Qh4b5B5OHcRxsQ2xt32svww2urttsYWIbDuzzjRW(ISPHkssBzh(kkR3qnqwrnpN(0Wxxp5xZq(mpeAxJD)H86S1vNRjN)f(wSVUPTHSHPLLPHSLKUeZlmRT84MUj0STod8AlDzDdfwhOHukH3j4M6k6k2kAMQA6sA2622QmRA1iqD)ufElE91vnSSTnvKuSumKGY4bD012M(mfyx855CoDh0B4VCyEW(fXYOmaF0YffPf)pi)Oa5aT4N4eFSEvrX5Fjyph(8kEylNF73BDjPBdO8nNgxXUl0ab(XZ99hfN849y0NphIijpEn2pe9ORqZKhfVyX4I3OOcYTmnI9KxX3TZaop8ykjvexzDSTFjbFCcCyrzua8gHQOAvEJ9X(lWHZxWsV1nvTvmS1vunLaOqbOHBhUf)(H5RN3LJzUv02kC0lErTPfYpNlNp9sXBVXpJfKGfVv3QnRva)6UbzivSu3Dwuo)gR4JBZyHMhyv44wmF7tTpKUaX8YULwsjZHJWeOtfQmmmNnmLnGydufMm2Wu2asPs3l)q7ZQtNv8URG49IZcIakMw8EQo9TWWH7KWguwr34qLd4k3cEaDA4bCkBg7)DnqNofMaqjW7xWnZCCQWleYQPxriVd7Z1f8sweWHjyByy9K3UEIP0(TjY8Q2SDB7ct0wUOJXIu7Qh)73vg)OVBr15)HB5lLXqupH3Uq7gP)(BY6udVyD0FYwSnJUSj0yGQ2xK(BBrJdz0QLbBBdiMMAgAAkMakuXs2OObK6Ra(v(RK8TwGUAv06Pa(xeF6o0MFZ)AnFn8PnWZLFe8cvkZFmScBrVnXk0e0Sk1qnmh)NKCiavw8vSn6xuO(TgNPyPQCG(5hqMK3mzsEbzs((Kj5FNjtkjfYzKc5msHauDmc70cY(Dh8d4xfC)U7kF1gdlnBddllBvOFnzPQDPvwwK3WAIBGt6Gi5LF8dFHE(0mumv0T11KLS1adjSwt)wGFh68R8nv4x9mmttHDH3F(

!TR16snUXs43L8RDtbSA0fFPQKTklWMLeV2CSeHDpfLThBn2wbHKJUWc8d)SF6EMr3TmM6KCojvTflksT6UNE6zMV(RfzkzQ9ulkCjEQv0ul1ZigNzm16HPwo4)GxUGU8ENWGTNh4feccgr4)tLFvJFvF6ifWkWflccDyHMstMAz65(Yl0qNDZTdc8IDbrpnE1Qiwm4b1Zuvv1jQeLUATHbnoy5JSWi3aFWRenf1u)nDXuRNLMn40okkgDiDv062wxxrrz6Qtn0GjH)YnbHxh46dXX59hz3FsQ9wUVWWiw(yAaONkO4utHp1u4tnf(uJGtm6YyiUIWesumnmwKXC9DL3TcUnAd)E4P4q31RHPIWN2zc43(8wg4VKqk4QKfShz(XwjRw5(0uRzN3ZYEMLDVjGI83m16tmQx8MCDVoKX1166(dhcI3Y88UYjseglahzTj4BJ9H3W)V9Ga)rya9PpWKkLGrT1wp6Zqez5WqJS5r1N6p86b3muOuEmhNMbEKzle(5ahMmZisH9Dwd2B9hj0q2U5ds882n)2nUXmmjfZc9PE)w6ARQoo)JHvRXBtZQ42pM3k5YN5yB7XFEy)bqAW1jnhSBUjfYPWkT7du0WIRgY8QFGpC1bYUOcZecJyld8Hue45hOU(hV2zRQhN(OfHqEgwUPXum)i3voaLksXwNpPF)rtTaBw5UwUQXtHx5Z3vcgLGZ5FHCZq3HTgFzCcmglPE8eoANJBHSMxaLFmnguWpwfV9He4Kw2YgUZIVYxwUq)AID9xhgKSTM8LE0OO9lDg13zgSnCzTxVxHoUqeTeK8CTxfsxYAiq1QjFL4izDNe4v3jBFCBdt4Ki2mXKdazIqGIkAGUKTggjX6Ni9GZ98d31XTkSxofkQXDcPaId6O1YqJ0TfrZODx1wDaGn99Fu5b3WWGYWI6T162HORQ1PnXORIoACRYHEm7P4KqgMIIPWjttyNhKtC4hMTmh2F0fnaJU8vW(BZb)Dyr0y8SbdJS3iIzASDfIwaRTS7654m2p6UBz077bEn6UpZCCP3zl0m6obyZmjktXZt7fX51XKHWmojQrKwCNcxoxBZsqQPqctTiza3NNFsTcK7bH9XHHRUzvW98b366H9(A)jZM0)Y(JMDXvw9GvVlWHro2WEMaHROEi8VP4HfSn0hDf7CocC)xFeBQYWPef(B2lsnhm7zoAMW3ltIIdEqEwKVvZuUNBIeZdU1UKQnGbBr92UHIvUTEIF9z(vUdmZ91L532l)2bj(lH9LWv0ZVBByWAyFw0j7MhsGlRXllWlu8sOkkdVSaVqvF)UFz3CXpEbWuC38K06w)8U53alPIhF3pi2h8dnAWNPpvXgqYHm76GVXcZmH)0RQEXbjvWbm68GhwqJZflFg9GsUu3vch2B1kgKf9xluRGFNhVH5xYCYU5aiuUpkM1YU)dLtoWp56Np7tV9dfNKzkMFxidGq8ZC5jPQFsAGDcgwfmecWmytCdv(5DTwifuXE6NKuI(RMKbspWscw54gTeMoSz8OJJ2PKDma2z)nxhG94G26T6s6QQRamM70TvlS8qB5uk1ioTdV3p(IBhDZFOFjHdunHxarIaTH5UEdwPsXG0XakvPQzqAr6i9wtCt2lpG9ZOOHkWvOvHDpiCmn8(B5ZWref5ZIkIFrKhC(DaWG5a7d4zJSYLTBRyOb9q0gMbTieE5sJgQ(X96KIzQsseLp7DJ9yrZsidbFNd3tHSDPJVMecnUr0jWIA48nuWAFfLs7M4nuqQqzUY1JkwPAllCj4aziAPPjEDzXlQO3Sa4rAmKNS(PJVreyh)VZXOX2AO(pFOcqUWwYzhM9cPrgd7He3cAyT(GbEBaiaCatrhiF1goiWBiTsdKLjhvyJ6xf7OkEstUxiRrryuNb)MTThjlnlAd1j4BFjTz2SIPGNW3l1sCB6Qox0rKo46TkaN5dcDFz38)vc1bp8b9XxE8pIwNlO9xtJ2tjPYZZXItqcqwBEypA8O(fcgXwJrC4rUWsNwVA0iKFYvx(j70ZXzdNI0aemWD1Z5RNz(w8jciQPM(LQM(OBKlWwgw8IlIeAae(n6O2QlaM0rVTUej84q(IGcKGlTUT3KHJp)xZvltI5brf57ImZPW37Il4h76jr9e4EMLjhVN2jkBcu7Ar5ghK7bfhN4C7pqh4Pm0K83gO3v3GO2vrrTLIANoyLhdJsKaZRDwKs2RZWBp0cFUa1VQm9mZL(ppMEVvsrYHjK5utgmvbgyvLUWlHvMhx2W8rGI3zTmsPUvGxK8hHhfC5Q9smeWx9oYPsp((FK8bLZ0mY1Te)VsJ9pvASB05KdfuVt6TtHbfiG(JG6V24ln(JC2PIPDXjj3G5hkK1(VkIvAi0QZGfC3jslpPiFwcNZkOp8ZHzUwSPR)xWDfRih5IWvsSAokMD9()pNgHDqysdV7MRon)PtTqdK2D(RxmJR3Ne41J0uk8TgSc8qkV4VxZpXTBEALYxca4KmQEiM3((kpCp764WG05O()g)Z8KX8(O)uGsk6ikj4w126QeshT0sjCw5xApg4z25xVwXhjRGbI4JSG8)aa(GqxGvLCH9tJNC1)E8i7EdRtjp7JnPBObLSm6cCGnq0zC00EJF1gmFEC0WRxZPrM5Tuv0jT7cKP0iDHkR)jXmpT01HOC7gZEyeS8i6gIFUayFI53suPfCNHSZAw8(PTEqY7hKSDdu5RqVwgEzXB5pgvfQ(Ijbg4ntFFpF4OYdPzZu3)4plhJYYQ(TKkL1(7gr(gOU(Ds7hhP9kmK)lLYE9geAGXEjA9)dN0(rZq)n(biY(JXAqmotx3OJIs7oevJ)0RtND(5qfI3x90ScXPL62tDy0wBoWsEb8gR2wTS8HR(Mxo)yPBuO6mV09JpTyZ93FFRLRB)gQtV)6WfQ(MxtUXVZEnQELBqRABxn3R2EA0Qq7BvAiZS63DVx1V7(t)FOrmrDN3CJy1n77nI99gXE7nIvQfSs)zUE9)xvOPpesHoUk1j2rPVSy0JWbsaWdUD6)5
```

You will get those results:

[The top two bluewish squares are the code you are looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi5HX.jpg)